# How to custom EditText font only and keep other same as original?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I create this EditText to use custom font

This method is no problem if it is TextView

If it is EditText, the text will show at wrong position, and I cannot edit the text, click the edittext, the keyboard will not display on screen

How can I fix these problems?

```
public class GothamBookEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    String font="Gotham-Book.ttf";
    public GothamBookEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font));
    }

    public GothamBookEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font));
    }

    public GothamBookEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font));
    }
}
```

[image]

---

This is styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@color/bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGreyWord</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorGreyWord</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorGreyWord</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGreyWord</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Your custom class looks OK. Is that loaded from a layout? If so, what's that look like? Also, what theme/style is it using?

Comment: I use this `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"`

Comment: I don't think that would do it. Do you have an `editTextStyle` attribute defined in your app's theme?

Comment: I posted the styles.xml, and `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` is set to application tag in manifest, not activity.

Comment: Hmm, dunno. It really looks like you're somehow setting a `TextView` style on your custom `EditText`. It's not in the code, 'cause you're calling the `super` in the two-parameter constructor, but I don't see anything in your themes, either.

Comment: Oh, wait a second. Which theme specifically are you using on the `Activity` your `GothamBookEditText` is in? I suspect it's the Material theme, in which case, that's likely your problem. Make sure you're using an AppCompat theme on that `Activity`. In fact, you should just be using AppCompat everywhere.

Comment: After I change to this `<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` in styles.xml, and use the theme to application, now everything is fine.